# More than 1 caching storage in Spring Boot app

Tags: spring-boot, redis, hazelcast, spring-cache

I am facing a strange issue - I have hazelcast and redis in my project. Suddenly all `@Cacheable` annotations are putting entries only to hazelcast cache, even if the particular cache name is configured via redis cache builder:

```
    @Bean
    fun redisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer(): RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer? {
        return RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer { builder: RedisCacheManagerBuilder ->
            builder
                .withCacheConfiguration(
                    MY_CACHE,
                    RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().entryTtl(Duration.ofDays(3))
                )
        }
    }
```

Using cache:

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = [CacheConfig.MY_CACHE])
```

```
@Cacheable(value= [CacheConfig.MY_CACHE])
```

Both does not work and forwards requests to hazelcast only. How to solve this? Using different cacheManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, only 1 caching provider is in use to cache data, such as in the service or data access tier of your Spring [Boot] application using [Spring's Cache Abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache) and infrastructure components, such as the `CacheManager` and [caching annotations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-annotations).

When multiple caching providers (e.g. *Hazelcast* and *Redis*) are on the classpath of your Spring Boot application, then it might be necessary to declare which caching provider (e.g. ***Redis***) you want to [solely] use for caching purposes. With this arrangement, Spring Boot allows you to declare your intentions using the `spring.cache.type` property as explained in the ref doc, [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/io.html#io.caching.provider) (see first **Tip**). Valid values of this property are defined by the enumerated values in the [`CacheType` enum](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/CacheType.html).

However, if you want to cache data using multiple caching providers at once, then you need to explicitly declare your intentions using this approach as well.

> DISCLAIMER: It has been awhile since I have traced through Spring Boot auto-configuration where caching is concerned, and how it specifically handles multiple caching providers on the application classpath, especially when a specific caching provider has **not** been declared, such as by explicitly declaring the `spring.cache.type` property. However, and again, this may actually be your intention, to use multiple caching providers in a single `@Cacheable` (or `@CachePut`) service or data access operation. If so, continue reading...

To do so, you typically use 1 of 2 approaches. These approaches are loosely described in the core Spring Framework's ref doc, [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-cache-resolver).

1 approach is to declare the cacheNames of the caches from each caching provider along with the `CacheManager`, like so:

```java
@Service
class CustomerService {

  @Cacheable(cacheNames = { "cacheOne", "cacheTwo" }, cacheManager="compositeCacheManager")
  public Customer findBy(String name) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

In this case, "cacheOne" would be the name of the `Cache` managed by caching provider one (e.g. *Redis*), and "cacheTwo" would be the name of the `Cache` managed by caching provider two (i.e. "Hazelcast").

> DISCLAIMER: You'd have to play around, but it might be possible to simply declare a single `Cache` name here (e.g. "Customers"), where the caches (or cache data structures in each caching provider) are named the same, and it would still work. I am not certain, but it seems logical this would work as well.

The key (no pun intended) to this example, however, is the declaration of the `CacheManager` using the `cacheManager` attribute of the `@Cacheable` annotation. As you know, the [`CacheManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/CacheManager.html) is the Spring SPI infrastructure component used to find and manage [`Cache`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html) objects (caches from the caching providers) used for caching purposes in your Spring managed beans (such as `CustomerService`).

I named this `CacheManager` deliberately, "***composite**CacheManager*". Spring's Cache Abstraction provides the [`CompositeCacheManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/support/CompositeCacheManager.html) implementation, which as the name suggests, composes multiple `CacheManagers` for use in single cache operation.

Therefore, you could do the following in you Spring [Boot] application configuration:

```java
@Configuration
class MyCachingConfiguration {

  @Bean
  RedisCacheManager cacheManager() {
    // ...
  }

  @Bean
  HazelcastCacheManager hazelcastCacheManager() {
    // ...
  }

  @Bean
  CompositeCacheManager compositeCacheManager(RedisCacheManager redis, HazelcastCacheManager hazelcast) {
    return new CompositeCacheManager(redis, hazelcast);
  }
}
```

> NOTE: Notice the `RedisCacheManager` is the "default" `CacheManager` declaration and cache provider (implementation) used when no cache provider is explicitly declared in a caching operation, since the bean name is "cacheManager".

Alternatively, and perhaps more easily, you can choose to implement the [`CacheResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheResolver.html) interface instead. The [*Javadoc*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheResolver.html#resolveCaches(org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheOperationInvocationContext)) is rather self-explanatory. Be aware of the Thread-safety concerns.

In this case, you would simply declare a `CacheResolver` implementation in your configuration, like so:

```java
@Configuration
class MyCachingConfiguration {

  @Bean
  CacheResolver customCacheResolver() {
    // return your custom CacheResolver implementation
  }
}
```

Then in your application service components (beans), you would do:

```java
@Service
class CustomerService {

  @Cacheable(cacheNames = "Customers", cacheResolver="customCacheResolver")
  public Customer findBy(String name) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

> DISCLAIMER: I have not tested either approach I presented above here, but I feel reasonably confident this should work as expected. It may need some slight modifications, but should generally be the approach(es) you should follow.

If you have any troubles, please post back in the comments and I will try to follow up.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. Very appreciated. However, I solved a bit differently - disabling HazelcastAufoconfiguration did the trick - thing is I am using hazelcast directly, not with Spring abstraction. Anyways, I think this response will help others when having 2 caches and accessing both of them with spring.

Comment: No worries. Glad you figured out a way. This is one of the many reasons that makes Spring really robust is there is typically always more than 1 way to solve the problem. Disabling auto-configuration is certainly 1 way. However, just be careful in this approach since it can snowball on you. I typically like to be very explicit in my configuration (opt-in rather than opt-out) making it clear what is applied and what is not.  Good luck!